# Getting a requestError status 410 when working with youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using python to make an API call to retrieve a Youtube playlist according to someone's channel ID. Here is what I was instructed to put as the code:

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

youtube_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
playlist = raw_input("Please enter the user ID: ")
url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"
playlist_url = url + playlist + "/playlists"

video_feed = youtube_service.GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed(playlist_url)

print "\nPlaylists for " + str.format(playlist) + ":\n"
for p in video_feed.entry:
  print p.title.text
```

After running the code, I get a response error that looks like this.
`gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 410, 'body': 'No longer available', 'reason': 'Gone'}`

After delving into this issue, this was caused by using an API that turned out to be deprecated (v2). The purpose of this code was to basically list out the playlist given the youtube channel ID that was prompted to the user. How can I translate this into code that will work according to the v3 API?

EDIT: Never mind, this is not being maintained, this is the old version!

Comment: Check the following link, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list. It has sample code in python as well